# Is there a WinForm control inspector application?

Tags: .net, winforms, debugging

I'm looking for something that provides interactive meta-data about a running .NET WinForms application.

Basically, I'd like to be able to hover over a running WinForms application and have the inspector highlight the various controls and let me inspect properties such as size, position, parent, etc.

I could have sworn I've seen this somewhere, but all my searching is turning up nada.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

I believe you're looking for [Hawkeye](http://hawkeye.codeplex.com/). You may also look at [GitHub](https://github.com/odalet/Hawkeye2) for a more recent version.

Comment: Wow. Hawkeye is seriously cool. Not only does it solve my "observation" problem, but it allows me to experiment in realtime with the UI (change properties, etc) and see what would happen. Very very nice.

Comment: wfSpy also allows you to change the properties at runtime.

Comment: Looks like it would be cool, but when I drag-drop the target on my app, I'm getting "The system cannot find the file specified". On Hawkeye's web page, the contact link leads to a 404.

Comment: Hawkeye has been open sourced and is now on Codeplex: http://hawkeye.codeplex.com/

Comment: How do you use it? I'm confused. I dragged the X to a control in my app, now Hawkeye says "<target in different process. release selection to hook>"

Answer (score 10):

[WinForms Spy](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/wfspy.aspx) is a good one. The codeproject version doesn't have a draggable cross hairs but there is a [version out there that added it](http://www.cplotts.com/2009/10/28/an-ode-to-wfspy/).

Comment: This one definitely deserves an honorable mention. It's a good tool for viewing the overall heirarchy. But Hawkeye is awesome.

Comment: The way I like to think of it: wfSpy is very easy to use while Hawkeye is quite a bit more powerful. I usually start using wfSpy first and then bring out the big guns (Hawkeye) if needed.

Answer (score 4):

Try the nuget package: [WinForm.Inspector.Tool](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WinForm.Inspector.Tool/#)

**Setup documentation**

- Instantiate the Inspector in your project.

  `Inspector inspector = new Inspector();`
- Ignore specific controls ex. buttons.

  `inspector.IgnoreTypes = new Type[] { typeof(Button) };`
- Skip controls ex. invisible and disabled.

  `inspector.SkipChilds = GetChildAtPointSkip.Invisible | GetChildAtPointSkip.Disabled;`

Run your project and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F8</kbd> to open the ControlViewer.

Hold down "Alt" and move your mouse over the controllers to select them.

[image]

Comment: is there a standalone version?

Answer (score 3):

For a 2021 response the best is the Windows SDK Inspect.exe

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-10-sdk/

Run the inspect.exe from C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin<version>\x64 or x86