# Tool for examining the structure of a windows forms application

Tags: winforms, winapi, controls, spy++

does anybody know a tool for examining the **structure of a windows forms application**? I want to get information about every control on the form like **buttons, labels** etc.
I tried Spy++ but it tells me only some information about the window structure, but nothing about the **internal controls**.

Thanks!
Mark

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [Document Outline](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/46xf4h0w(VS.90).aspx) in Visual Studio?

> You can use the outline to do the
>   following in Windows Forms
>   applications in Visual Studio:
>
> - View the logical structure of a Form or a UserControl.
> - Put user input focus on deeply nested controls that may be hard to
>     select on the Form or UserControl
>     itself.
> - Move controls from one parent to another parent.
> - See controls that may be visually hidden by other controls.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the AutoIt Window Info tool, it is similar to Spy++, but it may offer some additional data.

http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/intro/au3spy.htm

Answer (score 1):

This question seems to be asking the same thing and actually has a couple of good answers:

[Is there a WinForm control inspector application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2814789/is-there-a-winform-control-inspector-application)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into [Active Accessibility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms971350.aspx).  Assuming that the application just uses standard controls (or is accessibility enabled), MSAA will allow you to interact with the controls as a tree.